# No puedo efectuar la función recursiva ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: javascript

Necesito crear un array con los número de otro array, pero esta array de donde tengo que extraer número tiene objetos.

entonces al final necesito sumar los números, pero la suma la se hacer, lo que no se es porque la resucursividad para agregar todos los numeros en la array que cree no se agregan 1 por 1 sino sigue saliendome los objetos.

```
var array = [1,2,[3,4],5,[6,[7,8]]];

var Varfunt = function(array){    
  var numeroparasumar=[];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (typeof array[i] === "objeto") {
      numeroparasumar.push(Varfunt(array[i]));
    }else{
      numeroparasumar.push(array[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Solo necesito que el nuevo array quede así, no estoy pudiendo llamar a la recursión bien.

```
numerosparasumar =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: la comparación con "objeto" funciona? No debería ser "object"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu *array* de entrada no contiene objetos, sino otros *array* en su interior.

Además, haces un `push( )` de lo que te devuelve la llamada recursiva a tu función `Varfunt( )` ... que no tiene ningún `return`, por lo que siempre te añadirá un `undefined`.

Y, por último, aunque devolvieras algo ... devolverías un *array*, con lo que tampoco coseguirias tu objetivo.

Este último punto puede solventarse utilizando el [operador de propagación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator).

El resultado final quedaría:

```js
var array = [1,2,[3,4],5,[6,[7,8]]];

function Varfunct( arr ) {
  var result = [ ];

  for( var idx = 0; idx < arr.length; ++idx ) {
    if( Array.isArray( arr[idx] ) ) {
      result.push( ...Varfunct( arr[idx] ) );
    } else {
      result.push( arr[idx] );
    }
  }

  return result;
}

console.log( Varfunct( array ) );
```

#### Nota

Tal y como indica @Marcos, Javascript ya proporciona un método nativo para realizar justamente esto: [Array#flat( )](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/flat).

Usandola, la operación es trivial:

```js
var array = [ 1, 2, [ 3, 4 ], 5, [ 6, [ 7, 8 ] ] ];

console.log( array.flat( Infinity ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `reduce` también

```js
var array = [1,2,[3,4],5,[6,[7,8]]];

Varfunt = (arr) =>
    arr.reduce((p, c) => Array.isArray(c) ?  p.concat(Varfunt(c)) : p.concat(c), []);

console.log(Varfunt(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes que utilizar un segundo parametro con el arreglo que estas construyendo, si no, en cada llamada estás comenzando a crear un arreglo diferente. Al salir de cada llamada, el arreglo sigue como estaba antes de la llamada.

```
var array = [1,2,[3,4],5,[6,[7,8]]];

var Varfunt = function(array, target){    

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (typeof array[i] === "objeto") {
      numeroparasumar.push(Varfunt(array[i], target));
    }else{
      target.push(array[i])
    }
  }
}

var target = []
varFunt(array, target)
```